# How to run selenium scripts in virtual machine without using Selenium Grid?

Tags: java, selenium, virtual-machine

On Local machine can execute my script but, there is need to execute selenium script from my local to Virtual Machine. I tried Selenium Grid, Jenkins but, our system have some restriction ? Any other options ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, a bit more information is needed.
Depending on the OS for Windows you could use scheduled tasks and start them remotely, for Linux you could use remote ssh execution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).